# POST Value getting error in ios 9 (NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, post

i trying with these code but i getting error message like these only

ERROR message:-NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9813

URL:- http://www.xxxxx.com/XXX/rest/files/downloadFile/en/linto/

Header:- Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

RAW:-  phoneNumber=%2B15163120019&uname=test

RESPONSE HEADER:Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1

Content-Type: text/xml

Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Date: Wed, 24 Feb 2016 05:03:05 GMT
Raw
Parsed

XCODE version :7.2.1
MY code:-

```
NSURLSessionConfiguration *defaultConfigObject = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSURLSession *defaultSession = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration: defaultConfigObject delegate: nil delegateQueue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue]];

NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.indusaudio.com/WeeAudio/rest/files/downloadFile/en/linto/"];
NSMutableURLRequest * urlRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[urlRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSString * params =@"phoneNumber=%2B15163120019&uname=test";

[urlRequest setHTTPBody:[params dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
[urlRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLSessionDataTask * dataTask =[defaultSession dataTaskWithRequest:urlRequest
                                                   completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
                                                       NSLog(@"Response:%@ %@\n", response, error);
                                                       if(error == nil)
                                                       {
                                                          // NSString * text = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                                                           //NSLog(@"Data = %@",text);
                                                       }

                                                   }];
[dataTask resume];
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to write this line without slash

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.indusaudio.com/WeeAudio/rest/files/downloadFile/en/linto/"];
```

to

```
NSURL * url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.indusaudio.com/WeeAudio/rest/files/downloadFile/en/linto/"];
```

Comment: There is some issue with your server, please ask go Daddy support. Thanks

Comment: if i do like with out slash i getting message like these.

Comment: Response:(null) Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1202 "The certificate for this server is invalid. You might be connecting to a server that is pretending to be “www.indusaudio.com” which could put your confidential information at risk." UserInfo={NSURLErrorFailingURLPeerTrustErrorKey=<SecTrustRef: 0x7fca49cbe810>, NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Would you like to connect to the server anyway?, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=3, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=-9813, NSErrorPeerCertificateChainKey=

Comment: i found the issue, please use http in place of https in your URL

Comment: @lintojacob please upvoat my answer

Answer (score 0):

iOS9 requires the server to only support TLSv1.2,exception additions must be made in the app plist to work around.

Add this key in your `.plist`:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <!--Include to allow all connections (DANGER)-->
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
      <true/>
</dict>
```

See more at [Steven Peterson's Blog](http://ste.vn/2015/06/10/configuring-app-transport-security-ios-9-osx-10-11/).